# User Agent Sniffing with Regex in Express has 50% failure rate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I have a regex defined in my express router to figure out if the UA is mobile or not, and depending on if it is or not, render a different page.

Upon testing on our production site, it has a 25% - 50% failure rate.

I'd like to know the root cause and a fix.

Thank you.

Index.js

```
  const moment = require('moment');
        var _ = require('lodash');
        var mobileRegex = new RegExp(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i, 'ig');

    ......
    .....
    .....

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

      if (mobileRegex.test(req.headers['user-agent']) == true) {
          console.log('User-Agent: ' + req.headers['user-agent']);
        res.render('index-mobile')
      } else {
        res.render('index');
      }
    });

    router.get('/([\*])', function(req,res, next) { //Escaping * because cloudflare page rules aren't built right
      res.redirect('/')
    });

etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "failure" you mean mobile devices aren't getting detected?

Browser sniffing just isn't particularly reliable. You could try using something like [WhichBrowser](https://github.com/WhichBrowser/Parser) but you'd have to keep it up to date. Mozilla themselves [recommend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) simply testing the user agent string for "Mobi", so you might see a smaller failure rate just doing that.

Comment: Correct. By failure I mean it's loading the wrong page. Why is regex unreliable? The user agent is the same no matter what. To me this means it's a js issue with the way I am doing things, no?

Comment: No, what I mean is that the regex is likely a long way from reliably detecting all mobile devices out there. Because there are tens of thousands of different devices out there and most of them are lying through their teeth about what they actually are. If you mean that the detection is intermittently failing for one and the same device then I'd be very interested in the console output...

Comment: "It is because of g (global) flag. RegExp constructor is extra too, literal will suffice. mobileRegex remembers (in lastIndex property) index of the last match and the next test (or exec) starts from there." - shvaikalesh on Reddit